# swift Autolayout 3 button set horizontally width manage according to text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have to set button in one child view max button is three and minimum is zero 
I Try to set Horizontally button but its take always equal width , I am Try to set left aligned , with depend on button text width , and one more problem is if any one button is missing i mean to say if button array count is two and one then not show any one , please give me solution 
Here is my code

```
 let button1  = UIButton()
                  let button2  = UIButton()
                 let button3  = UIButton()
            print(getChannelname)
            for var i = 0; i < getChannelname.count; i++ {

                if(i == 0)
                {
                    button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
                    button1.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    button1.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    button1.setTitle("#\(getChannelname[i])" , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    button1.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)

                }else if (i == 1)
                {
                    button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
                    button2.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    button2.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    button2.setTitle("#\(getChannelname[i])" , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    button2.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)
                }else
                {

                    button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
                    button3.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    button3.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    button3.setTitle("#\(getChannelname[i])" , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    button3.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)
                }


            }
            cell.viewChannel!.addSubview(button1)
            cell.viewChannel!.addSubview(button2)
            cell.viewChannel!.addSubview(button3)
            cell.viewChannel!.layer.borderWidth = 2


            let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1,
                attribute: .Bottom,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: cell.viewChannel!,
                attribute: .Bottom,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 0.0);
            cell.viewChannel!.addConstraint(leftConstraint);

               cell.viewChannel!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[b1]-0-[b2(==b1)]-0-[b3(==b1)]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllBottom, metrics: nil, views: ["b1": button1, "b2": button2, "b3": button3]))
```

array of name like this

```
**ONE** 
(
    channelsnamelonggergo,
    General
)
**two**
(
    trndnl,
    jive,
    Banter
)
**Three**
(
    channelsnamelonggergo,
    Trending,
    Local
)
**Four**
(
    scoobydoobyparampaa,
    channelsnamesarebigmerge,
    enternewchannelsjive
)
```

Please Give me soultion.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood the question, you can manage to do this by using an UIStackView and creating the three UIButtons inside it.

Here is a link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/